# Why and where I am mistaken? Volume of upper hemisphere of $S^2$

Tags: calculus

I have to calculate the volume of a hemisphere of $S^2$. My intuition says to me that once I can cover it by an infinite quantity of circles of radis $r$ whose are is equals $\pi r^2.$ Then this is the function I have to integrate to obtain the volume, and finally I have:

$$V = \int_{0}^1 \pi r^2 dr = \pi/3$$

And this is not correct! Where am I mistaken?

Comment: If you cover a hemisphere with radius $r$ with circles, the total area of your circles is $2\pi r^2$, since the surface area of $S^2$ is $4\pi r^2$. The projection on the equatorial plane does not preserve the area of a circle.

Comment: That's the area of a cone.  You are assume that at a height of x the radius is (1 -x) and by symmetry the is equivalent to x = r.  I.e. the radius are preportional to the height.  That's true for a cone but not a sphere.  at a height of x the radius is $\sqrt{1 -x^2}$ .  So $V = \int_0^1 \pi(1 - r^)dr$ should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have computed could be interpreted as the volume of a rotational solid (a cone actually), where the line $y=x$ is rotated around the $x$-axis and integrated from $0$ to $1$. The "radial" element is $\pi x^2$ and then integrated as $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

---

To find the volume of the upper hemisphere:

$$V=\iiint_EdV=\iint_A z(x,y)dA$$

where $E$ is the 3D region you want the volume of, and $z(x,y)$ is the height of the region as a function of $x$ and $y$.

For your upper unit hemisphere, you have $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ so that

$$V=\iint_D \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} dA$$

where $D$ is the unit disk in the $xy$-plane. This is not a very nice integral, so we change to polar coordinates:

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-r^2} r dr d\theta.$$

Now this is a standard double integral which can be solved with substitution.

Answer (score 1):

You are integrating over $r$, but your $r$ is not varying from $0$ to $1$ uniformly. The picture you are painting is that you are trying to sum up the infinite number of circles starting from the circle of radius $0$ at the "pole" of $S^2$ and ending at the circle of radius $1$ at the "equator" of $S^2$. While your bounds of integration are varying from $0$ to $1$, these values are not values of $r$ but are instead values of the $z$-coordinate within $S^2$.

Since you are really integrating over $z$, you need to make your $r$ a function of $z$. The equation of $S^2$ is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, and our radius needs to be the radius of the circle at a particular level-set of $z$ of this sphere. So by doing the substitution $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, we get that $r = \sqrt{1-z^2}$. Then the integral should be

$$
 \int\limits_0^1 \pi r^2 \;\mathrm{d}z \;\;= \;\;
 \int\limits_0^1 \pi \left(1-z^2\right) \;\mathrm{d}z \;\;=\;\; \frac{2\pi}{3}
$$

as expected.

Comment: which is the correct interval?

Comment: thank you, I realize, the problem is the height.